# php Why can't I run a batch file?

Tags: php, batch-file

I have tried to run a batch file using PHP:

```
$script = "\\\MAFINFWWWPV02\D$\WebContent\\engsys.corp.ftr.com\BatchFiles\CopyFiles.bat";
exec($script,$ReturnArray,$ReturnValue);
//shell_exec($script);
//system('cmd /c $script');
//system($script,$ReturnValue);
```

None of these work! I've tried

```
var_dump($ReturnValue); echo "<br>";
var_dump($ReturnArray); echo "<br>";
```

to try and see what is going on, but I get what appears to be normal output like this:

> int(1)
>
> array(0) { }

But the files that I'm trying to copy with my bat file, which works fine when run manually, don't get copied!

**Edit additional question**

Do the `\` need to be escaped in the file address?

**EDIT 2**

Here's what I get from running `icacls`:

> CopyFiles.bat NT AUTHORITY\IUSR:(I)(RX)
>
> ```
>          NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
>
>          NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK:(I)(RX)
>
>          CORP\ibb601:(I)(F)
>
>          CORP\taw330:(I)(F)
>
>          CORP\mmm976:(I)(F)
>
>          BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
>
>          BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX,W)
> ```

I have full control and everybody else has at least read/execute.

**EDIT 3**

I have narrowed it down. It's not that the commands are not working it's that permission is denied to the files. Which I don't understand since everyone has write and read/execute access to the entire folder.

**EDIT 4**

I am running the commands from above trying to get it to work. I am using a function (`var_export(my_exec("shell_exec($script)"));`) to print what the errors are to my screen. I keep getting something like this:

> '\'shell_exec\' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I get a different one for each `shell_exec`, `system`, and `exec`. It just keeps saying that the command is not recognized. This is being executed on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 64-bit. Is there something that I'm doing wrong with the commands?

Function that I'm using to print errors (I found it on another post):

```
function my_exec($cmd, $input='')
    {
        $proc=proc_open($cmd, array(0=>array('pipe', 'r'), 1=>array('pipe', 'w'), 2=>array('pipe', 'w')), $pipes); 
        fwrite($pipes[0], $input);fclose($pipes[0]); 
        $stdout=stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);fclose($pipes[1]); 
        $stderr=stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);fclose($pipes[2]); 
        $rtn=proc_close($proc); 
        return array('stdout'=>$stdout,'stderr'=>$stderr,'return'=>$rtn); 
    }
```

Comment: The user that runs the web service probably doesn't have permissions to access that server, location or bat file and/or doesn't have permissions to access the files or the destination for copy.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I have made sure that I the user does have access for read/write to both of the file locations and also to the location of the .bat file.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Is there a way to see exactly which user is being used? Or to force it to use a certain user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work. Here's what I ended up with:

```
$script = chr(92) . chr(92) . 'MAFINFWWWPV02\D$\WebContent\engsys.corp.ftr.com\BatchFiles\CopyFiles.bat';
if (!file_exists($script))
{
    var_dump($script); echo " Script<br>";
    echo "Script doesn't exist!<br>";
    var_dump(!file_exists($script));
}
else
{
    system('cmd /c ' . $script); echo " <br>";
}
```

Sometimes I still get the `Script doesn't exist!` message, but that is usually when I'm connected to the #1 server and not the #2 server. The .nat looks like this:

```
echo off
SET source2="\\MAFINFWWWPV02\engsys.corp.ftr.com"

START /wait NET USE L: "\\MAFINFWWWPV01\engsys.corp.ftr.com" Password /user:UserName

xcopy %source2% L: /E /Y /Q

NET USE L: /DELETE
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape `\` when inside single quotes.

If you want to run a script, make sure is exists and is executable:

```
$script = '\\MAFINFWWWPV02\engsys.corp.ftr.com\CopyFiles.bat';

if (!file_exists($script) || !is_executable($script)) {
    // Im' sorry dave
}

// carry on...
```

If the script is run through a webserver, make sure the user running the service has execute rights, not your own user! `is_executable` only checks if the file is an executable, not if the user running the script has executable rights

Since your return code is `1`, you probably have some permission issue. A successful execution has return code `0`

Also consider the following note from the docs:

> Note: When safe mode is enabled, you can only execute files within the safe_mode_exec_dir. For practical reasons, it is currently not allowed to have .. components in the path to the executable.

To have a OS agnostic method of running exernal processes, have a look at the [Symfony Process component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html)

Comment: All users have read/execute permission. I tried doing just one check at a time to see which was the problem. It turns out that it's the `!is_executable($script)` that's the problem. But if everyone has execute permission what's the problem?

Answer (score -1):

after many hours. you should try

```
c:\\a\\b\\c
```

instead of
    c:\a\b\c